# $\lim_{h\to\infty}h^2\int_{0}^{1}e^{-ht}\left[f(t)-f(0)\right]dt=f'(0)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function with the derivative $f'$ continuous. Show that

$$\lim_{h\to\infty}h^2\int_{0}^{1}e^{-ht}\left[f(t)-f(0)\right]dt=f'(0)$$

This question is from my homework. I worked $8$ hours but only can show this equation equal to $f'(x_0)$ for some $x_0\in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I think the true limit is $\lim_{h \rightarrow +\infty}$, not  just any infinity.

---

**Hint:** Integration by parts and DCT. More precisely,
By IBP,
$$\begin{align}
h^2\int_{0}^{1}e^{-ht}\left[f(t)-f(0)\right]dt&=- h \int_{0}^1 [f(t)-f(0)]d(e^{-ht})\\
&=-h[f(1)-f(0)]e^{-h}+h\int_0^1e^{-ht}f'(t)dt
\\
&=-h[f(1)-f(0)]e^{-h}+\int_0^{\infty} \mathbb{1}_{[0,h]}(t)e^{-t}f'\left(\frac{t}{h}\right)dt
\end{align}$$

I think you can complete the work yourself from here.

Comment: OK, DCT=Dominated Convergence Theorem. But could you clarify a little how have you applied it?

Comment: Yeah, that's Dominated convergence theorem.  I used the DCT for the leftover integral in the formula. If the op spends enough time, he'll find that the function $t\mapsto \mathbb{1}_[0,h](t)f'(t/h)$ is bounded by a constant, namely $\|f'_{[0,1]}\|_{\infty}$, from which he can use DCT.

Comment: sorry I did't learn DCT and not sure what's [0,ℎ]() mean can you explained for me how you applied it?

Comment: If you didn't learn DCT, the work will be a little lengthier. You can try to prove for any continuous function $g$ on $[0,1]$, $$\lim_{h \rightarrow +\infty}  \int_0^1 g(t)he^{-ht}dt = g(0)$$ There should be some solution already presented on this site, if you don't like it you can try to prove it yourself.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen Fair enough. +1