# Show that $\lim_{x\to \infty} x^2 \int_0^1 e^{-tx} [f(t)-f(0)]\, dt = f'(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function.  Show that
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} x^2 \int_0^1 e^{-tx} [f(t)-f(0)]\, dt = f'(0)
.$$

I have tried using integration by parts to get that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x\to \infty} x^2 \int_0^1 e^{-tx} [f(t)-f(0)]\, dt &= \lim_{x\to \infty} \left[-xe^{-x}(f(1)-f(0)) + \int_0^1 x e^{-tx} f'(t)\, dt \right] \\ &= \lim_{x\to \infty} \int_0^1 xe^{-tx} f'(t)\, dt.
\end{aligned}
$$
At this point, I tried using the (first) mean value theorem for integrals.
$$
\int_0^1 xe^{-tx} f'(t)\, dt = xe^{-cx} f'(c)
$$
for some $c\in (0,1)$, which implies that
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} \int_0^1 xe^{-tx} f'(t)\, dt = 0
.$$
Would you be able to tell me where my error is?  Also, do you think using integration by parts is helpful to show that
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} x^2 \int_0^1 e^{-tx} [f(t)-f(0)]\, dx = f'(0)
?$$
Thank you for any advice you may have.

Comment: See [$\lim_{h\to\infty}h^2\int_{0}^{1}e^{-ht}\left[f(t)-f(0)\right]dt=f'(0)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4166323/lim-h-to-inftyh2-int-01e-ht-leftft-f0-rightdt-f0?noredirect=1) or [Show that the Laplace transform of a $C^1$ function $f$ equal to its derivative at $0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4166713/323432). Integration by parts is indeed helpful.

Comment: The formula in the title is wrong: integration is in dx.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that your approach does not work because $c$ depends on $x$, and so when you take limit $x \to \infty$ you cannot treat $c$ as a constant.